# Minimal QSystemTrayIcon example in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, qt5.4

I am studying how to build and deploy a Qt application with Ubuntu 12.04. I am working with Qt 5.4.2 which I downloaded [here](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.4/5.4.2/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.4.2.run). I installed it in the default location `~/Qt5.4.2`.

Currently I want to set a tray icon. My code is just the following:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QSystemTrayIcon *trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon();
    qDebug() << trayIcon->isSystemTrayAvailable();
    trayIcon->setIcon(QIcon("heart.png"));
    trayIcon->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

`heart.png` is from PyQt5's QSystemTrayIcon example, I got it from [here](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/desktop/systray/images/heart.png). I put it in the same directory as the source file.

I built the executable with the following commands.

```
~/Qt5.4.2/5.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake -config release
make
```

Running the created file shows the tray icon.

For deploying the app, I copied the following files into the same directory. I got them from `~/Qt5.4.2/5.4/gcc_64/lib`:

```
libicudata.so.53
libicui18n.so.53
libicuuc.so.53
libQt5Core.so.5
libQt5DBus.so.5
libQt5Gui.so.5
libQt5Widgets.so.5
```

I also copied `~/Qt5.4.2/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so` and placed it under a directory named `platforms`.

I tested adding a `qt.conf` file, but it doesn't seem to have an effect. Its contents are

```
[Paths]
Prefix = .
Binaries = .
```

I copied over this whole directory to a VM running an Ubuntu 12.04 live CD. Before running the binary I exported `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` so that it will find the included Qt libraries.

Unfortunately the tray icon is not shown when the program is run in the VM. The `qDebug` statement shows that the system tray is available though.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by editing the systray whitelist: http://www.howtogeek.com/68119/how-to-bring-app-icons-back-into-unitys-system-tray/